# Does Apple use a UICollectionView in the app switcher on iOS?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to implement a way of switching between views (cards with content) similar to Apple's **app switcher** on iOS. The one that appears when user taps Home button twice.

What technology is used there? Is it a `UICollectionView` with custom layout?
Does anyone know something about it?

[image]

Comment: For people voting to close - this question is not opinion based. I'm asking specifically whether it is done using UICollectionView